# Difficult Problem on Calculus of variation

Tags: calculus-of-variations

Consider the functional

$$J(y)=y^2(1)+\int_0^1 y'^2(x) \ dx$$ with $y(0)=1$ where $y\in C^2[0,1]$. If $y$ extremizes $J$ then find $y$.

Any hint will be appreciated.